# Nullable reference types - return type nullability by the accepted parameter

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a method, Foo, that accepts a string. It does something if the string is null and some other thing if it's not (null is a valid value). It then returns the same string.

Here is Foo with nullable reference types *disabled* in C# 8.0:

```
string Foo(string s)
{
    // Do something with s.
    return s;
}

void Bar()
{
    string s = "S";
    string s2 = Foo(s);

    string n = null;
    string n2 = Foo(n);
}
```

After I enable nullable reference types, `string n = null` gives a warning. This makes sense, since `string` is not nullable anymore. I convert its type to `string?`:

```
void Bar()
{
    string s = "S";
    string s2 = Foo(s);

    string? n = null; // X
    string? n2 = Foo(n);
}
```

And now `Foo(n)` warns me about Foo's new dislike of nullable strings. This also makes sense - Foo should accept a nullable string since it supports both null and non-null values. I change its parameter and therefore, return types to `string?`:

```
string? Foo(string? s)
{
    // Do something with s.
    return s;
}
```

This time it's `string s2 = Foo(s)`, complaining about Foo returning a `string?` and me trying to assign it to a `string`.

Is there a way for me to let the flow analysis understand the fact that when I'm supplying Foo a `string` (and not a `string?`), then its return value cannot be null?

Comment: Is this possible in a single method? No.

Comment: Though in theory it would be possible to write a flow analyzer that tracks "is nullability preserved by this method from its inputs to its output?" in practice that's not usually how it is done.

Comment: I wish code contracts had taken off.

Comment: Yeah me too, but they really fell into an awkward spot. The library and rewriter was sufficiently powerful that we did not feel like we had a strong reason to integrate it into the language, but the user perspective is they were not so compelling that people felt that the costs were worth the benefits if they weren't there "for free" in the language. I have some regrets about how that all played out.

Comment: We are contemplating some attributes to help with such scenarios. This specific scenario would use `[NullInNullOut]` (name is not finalized). https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26761

Comment: Great. Are generics being considered? `C<string?> M(C<string?> arg)`

Answer (score 1):

This could make the return value not null when the parameter `s` is not null.

```
// using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[return: NotNullIfNotNull("s")]
string? Foo(string? s)
{
    // Do something with s.
    return s;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate:  This was implemented in [dotnet/roslyn#37201](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/37201) and is documented in [Specify conditional post-conditions: `NotNullWhen`, `MaybeNullWhen`, and `NotNullIfNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#specify-conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just have two methods.  One that accepts a `string?` and returns a `string?`, and another that accepts a `string` and returns a `string`.   You probably want to implement the former in terms of the latter (check for null, if non-null, call other method, otherwise, handle the null case).

Having two methods is how you ensure that the return type differs based in the input type(s).

Comment: Currently, not working on the first preview of Visual Studio 2019. Nullability has no effect on method signature.

Comment: You can't overload based solely on nullability. If MSFT made nullability a modopt then it would work, but I believe that is not the plan.

Comment: Adding Nullable Reference Types to an existing project seems like it will be as much fun as a project that I worked on in the mid 1990s, taking a reasonable sized C++ project (written by experienced C programmers) and adding `const` to it so that it interop-ed properly with a strictly `const`-enable library we were adopting.  That was no fun at all (though it did result in much more solid code).